# How can you import a standard price book catalog in a scratch org with the data import command?

Tags: salesforcedx, lookup, scratch-org, pricebook, pricebookentry

When a scratch org is created its default price book is already created in the org. The JSON files with the dummy data in the repository, however, do not contain the ID of the price book record, or it contains the ID for another scratch org created some time ago. This can pollute the repository with unnecessary changes, or can cause the developer working with the project to have to edit the JSON file every time they need to import the data. Is there a way to import the price book ID dynamically?

Comment: This ends up being an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You can indeed store your data in your repo, using External ID values as the relationships between objects. You just can't use force:data:tree:import, but instead have to use the Bulk API. You'll find this works for a large number of standard objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use a different tool to accomplish your goals: `force:bulk:data:upsert`. Create a CSV file that contains, at minimum, the following fields: `Product2.Name`, `Pricebook2.Name`, `IsActive`, and `UnitPrice`. Then, specify the Product2 Name values, the Pricebook2.Name ("Standard Price Book"), active flags, and the unit prices. Include the currency field if you're using multicurrency. `force:bulk:data:upsert` uses the Bulk API, which can handle upserting with relationships via External ID values, and all (or at least most?) Name fields can act as an External ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (at this moment, Aug 6 2022) without some changes to the way the CLI works, with plugins or with automation.

To automate this one could use, for example - in a Unix environment - a bash script that uses the data query command followed by a command to replace a string of text and then use the tree import command, like this:

```bash
# Query the price book ID
pricebookId=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsStandard = TRUE" --json | jq '.result.records[0].Id')

# Replace a dummy string, such as "@standardPricebookId", in the JSON file to be
# uploaded, but generate a new temporary file instead.
cat data/pricebookentries_model.json  | sed 's/"@standardPricebookId"/'$pricebookId'/g' > data/pricebookentries.json

# Import the generated file with the price book ID on it
sfdx force:data:tree:import --plan data/plan.json

# Clean up by removing the generated file.
rm data/pricebookentries.json
```

Comment: Take a look at [SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility).